# ReactJS & Docker - can't start my app : react-scripts.js: not found

Tags: reactjs, docker

I use Docker to embed my ReactJS app, here is my `/app/Dockerfile` content:

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /app

# add app
COPY . ./

# install app dependencies
RUN npm install

RUN echo $(ls -1 /app/node_modules/react-scripts/bin)
# this outputs : react-scripts.js in the console

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And the part of my docker-compose.yml :

```
  app:
    container_name: searcher
    build:
      context: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - 3010:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks:
      - app-network
```

And as the title says, I always have this error : `react-scripts.js: not found` (or (`sh: /app/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js: not found` when I change path)

So I tried all things in my /app/package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    ....
```

Or:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
    ....
```

Or:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "/app/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts start",
    ....
```

I really don't understand this error, since the node_modules containts react-scripts plugin, what can I do more ?

Comment: I googled the error and people seem to be solving it by installing react-scripts globally but I'm not sure why react-scripts is not resolved from nodemodules

Comment: @vanshaj I also tried it, but I got the error `Cannot find module 'react'` ...

Comment: The `volumes:` hides the `node_modules` tree in the image.  I'd recommend deleting that block.  (Use a host Node environment for day-to-day development; `docker-compose up --build` to rebuild the image for integration testing.)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes indeed.. Thanks a lot. I wanted to explore this but I didn't find any informations

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in volumes - /app/node_modules to use the node module that is in the container

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).